# From roots to coefficients of a polynomial

Tags: algorithms, polynomials

Polynomials are usually written as a sum of powers (or various products of generators) and Google gives me lots of results on how to get from that to the form that is a product of degree-$1$ polynomials (where you can see where the polynomial vanishes), e.g.,

$$ x^2 - 1 = (x + 1) (x - 1) $$

I am looking for the other direction though, which is much easier, but still computationally expensive if done naively.

I have an array of $n$ values that the polynomial vanishes on. Can I somehow get the coefficients in $n \log n$?

Comment: How do you know if the polynomial only vanishes at the $n$ given points? Why not use standard terminology like "roots" and "factorization"?

Comment: Essentially, you want fast convolution. Have you tried using the FFT?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't always have the standard terminology in my head, but those would have indeed been better words. Also, it does indeed smell of FFT, but I didn't get it together at the time of writing. I think I have it now (edit: for my special case). Thanks! But I'm closing the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient algorithm to compute polynomial coefficients from its roots?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116643/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-compute-polynomial-coefficients-from-its)

Comment: @Jakube Yes, thanks!